# How to remove unwanted blank spaced in child fields in SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have created a report in SSRS-2012. It is a group by a report like one parent have multiple children. While previewing the report there have some unwanted space coming due to hide the row. Is there any way to remove unwanted space in ssrs report?

[image]

Comment: The image and what you state above do not seem to add up. Are you conditionally setting a group or row visibility to false, or are you using the remove duplicate feature?

Answer (score 0):

Select the relevant textboxes and set CanGrow to false in properties.

[image: Cangrow False]